# Search a string within double quotes after another string in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and seeking a bit of help here with java code.

```
String my string="text1=\"value1\" text2=\"value2\" text 3=\"value3\"";
```

I want to extract the string which in within quotes after the text2  string in myString. There is escape character after each of the inside quotes in myString. For some reason it is getting removed while posting.

My output should give me : value2

Can someone help me with it.

Regards

Comment: The escaping was removed probably because you didn't format your code with  [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), which should be used for code, errors and logs.

Comment: I am feeling like your string is a JSON fragment and, if so, you should use a parser on the entire string to extract the key and value.

Comment: Yes I parsed a Yaml file (it also contains xml part in it) into a text file and looked for a particular string to get that myString and now I need to get that value2 from that string

Comment: what exactly is meant by "There is escape character after each of the inside quotes in myString"? Do you mean the ``\`` **before** each quotes? These are not really there - just used to not have the inside quotes confused with the closing one when the literal string is typed (printed?)

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant before!

Comment: `String val = myString.replaceAll(".*text2=\"(.*?)\".*", "$1");` but as others have said, don't parse JSON 'manually' if that's what it is

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using regex :

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "text1=\"value1\" text2=\"value2\" text 3=\"value3\"";
        
        // Set regular expression to extract value from text2
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("text2=\"(.*?)\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
        
        // Check if match is found
        if (matcher.find()) {
            // Get value without "\"
            String value = matcher.group(1);
            // Print value
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to improve the code later so that it can return the values ​​of text1, text2 or text3, you can configure a String variable instead of directly passing "text2" in hard text inside "Pattern.compile(...)" method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "text1=\"value1\" text2=\"value2\" text 3=\"value3\"";
    String extractedValue = extractValueAfterText2(myString);
    System.out.println(extractedValue);
}

public static String extractValueAfterText2(String input) {
    int text2Index = input.indexOf("text2=");

    if (text2Index != -1) { // If "text2=" exists in the input string
        int valueStartIndex = input.indexOf("\"", text2Index) + 1;

        int valueEndIndex = input.indexOf("\"", valueStartIndex);

        if (valueStartIndex != -1 && valueEndIndex != -1) {
            return input.substring(valueStartIndex, valueEndIndex);
        }
    }
    return null; // Return null if "text2=" is not found or value is not properly enclosed in quotes
}
 }
```